# ¿De qué depende la cantidad de reportes máximos que puedo enviar diariamente?

Tags: soporte, reportes

A veces estoy revisando las colas y envío reportes, sobre todo a las mañanas. En estos meses me he dado cuenta de que mi cantidad de reportes máximos ha subido, de tener unos 11 al día ha pasado a, si no me equivoco, unos 20 al día.

¿Por qué es esto? ¿Se determina por la reputación? ¿Por las medallas? ¿Por los reportes útiles? ¿Se acumulan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Según se especifica en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149670):

- por defecto, 10 cada día
- un reporte extra por cada 2000 de reputación
- un reporte extra por cada 10 reportes útiles a nivel de red
- hasta un máximo de 100

Comment: Gracias señor moderador, no he buscado con las palabras adecuadas.